# Postgres query for IP and epoch timestamp within 24 hours, plus check number of results

Tags: python, postgresql

On the server we have an old Python web app which connects to a PostgreSQL DB table called 'transactions' has the following.

```
   ip           |        timestamp
----------------------------------------
84.36.154.96    |       1413330523
```

We need to query the transaction table for an IP with a timestamp from within 24 hours.

So far we think we have the following to match IP but are not sure how to add the search against the epoch timestamps...

```
result = db.query("SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE ip=" + ip + ";")
```

Any help on adding the timestamp query and sanity checking our current query would be appreciated. We also need to know how to check the number of results as a user can only continue if no result is found.

Comment: I'm getting there with the following manual bit of PostgreSQL, just need to get it to provide the timestamp itself ###### select * from transactions where ip='86.168.225.111' AND timestamp>(1441640544-86400); ######

Comment: Very quick, this seems to work. Please stop me if this is not a sane solution. ###### select * from transactions where ip='86.168.225.100' AND timestamp>(extract(epoch from now())-86400); ######

Answer (score 0):

Below is the solution I wrote. We are using the DB facility that comes with web.py.

```
result = db.query("SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE ip='" + df.ctx['ip'] + "' AND timestamp>(extract(epoch from now())-86400);")
if result:
    raise df.err('Only one purchase allowed every 24 hours')
```